# React JS setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am getting this error `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.` but I can't work out how to fix it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Loading1 from '../images/loading1.gif';

class LoadingSpinner extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
    this.timer = this.timer.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    loadingImg: Loading1,
    loading: true
  }

  timer(){
    var self = this;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
      if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 3000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
      }
      self.changeState();
    }, 2000);
  }

  changeState(){
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
    })
  }

  render() {


    const topMargin = {
      marginTop: "50px"
    }


    return (
      <div className="containter" style={topMargin}>
        <center>
          {this.state.loading ? <img src={this.state.loadingImg} onLoad=    {this.timer()} alt="Loading..." /> : <h2>Unable To Find What You Are Looking     For!</h2> }
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoadingSpinner;
```

this is my code that is causing the issue.

Basically I want it so that after the set amount of time it will change from the loading1.gif to say Unable to find what you are looking for. It does this but it throws the error `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.` which I can't get rid of.

This is how I am calling loading spinner

```
<Tab label="Applicant Details" value="GetCasePersonal">
     {this.state.GetCasePersonal.length === 0 ? <LoadingSpinner /> :
     <div>
         <ViewPersonalDetails Case={this.state.GetCasePersonal} />
     </div>
     }
</Tab>
```

Comment: Move your timer function to `componentDidMount`.  You're calling it from inside `render` which doesn't communicate your intentions very well.  More about life cycle functions here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @Kyle Still does it if i do it from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not use a `setInterval` function, you can do it with `setTimeout` easily and you should use a React lifecycle function to have a timeout instead of calling it onLoad of image.

```js
class LoadingSpinner extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.timeout = null;
    this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    loadingImg: '',
    loading: true
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    
    this.timeout = setTimeout( () => {
      console.log('I am changing state');
      this.changeState();
    }, 3000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
     clearTimeout(this.timeout); 
  }
  changeState(){
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
    })
  }

  render() {


    const topMargin = {
      marginTop: "50px"
    }


    return (
      <div className="containter" style={topMargin}>
        <center>
          {this.state.loading ? <img src={this.state.loadingImg} alt="Loading..." /> : <h2>Unable To Find What You Are Looking     For!</h2> }
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<LoadingSpinner/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: this gives me the same error im trying to get rid of

Comment: Well it doesn't in the snippet, the problem should then be arising somewhere else. I hope you have gotten rid of the onLoad and the timer function

Comment: it doesn't in the snippet because there is no console i said it works but it puts an error in console

Comment: You can always see the console logs in Chrome by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J. Even the snippet shows console logs, check in the above snippet

Comment: ok so why would this work but not in my code all i am doing is calling it from a parent

Comment: Maybe your compoent is unmounting before setting the state, try the updated code

Comment: Perfect Thank You Very Much

Comment: Worked perfectly for me :) Could you please specify why you should use setTimeout instead of setInterval?

Comment: @The reason being that the action needs to be performed just once and not repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

There's good documentation about this here
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

When dealing with such problems a good practice is to search in react facebook documentation.

```
private _isMount = false;

componentDidMount() {
  this._isMount = true;
}

componentWillUnmount()
{
    this._isMount = false;
}

timerJob()
{
    if(this._isMount == false)
        return;
    // setState
}
```

Comment: Although this will stop showing the Warning, it's not fully correct as you are using a flag, and not the React lifecycle to handle the events. The correct ways is to start the timer inside the `componentDidMount`, and not in the `render` method inside the `onLoad`.

Comment: @LuísBrito How would you do it